# Linear operator and dimension theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need some help with this problem:
Let be $V$ a finite vector space and $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a  linear operator. Suppose that $ \text{Rank}(T)=\text{Rank}(T^2) $, then prove that $\text{Image}(T) \cap \text{Kernel}(T) = \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
T^2:V\rightarrow V  
\end{align}
is equivalent to
\begin{align}
T:\operatorname{Im}T \rightarrow V.
\end{align}
By the first isomorphism theorem, we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im}T/ (\ker T\cap \operatorname{Im}T) \cong \operatorname{Im}T^2
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\dim [\operatorname{Im}T/ (\ker T\cap \operatorname{Im}T)] = \dim [\operatorname{Im}T^2] = \dim[\operatorname{Im}T].
\end{align}
However, we have
\begin{align}
\dim [\operatorname{Im}T/ (\ker T\cap \operatorname{Im}T)]= \dim[\operatorname{Im}T] -\dim [\ker T \cap\operatorname{Im}T].
\end{align}
Thus, this leads to 
\begin{align}
\dim [\ker T \cap\operatorname{Im}T]=0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \text{Image}(T)\cap \text{Ker}T\implies x=Ty $ and $Tx=0$.

Now $Tx=T^y=0$.

Since $\text{Rank } T=\text{Rank }T^2\implies \text{Kernel T}=\text {Kernel }T^2$

So $T^y=0\implies y\in \text{Kernel} T^2\implies y\in \text{Kernel T}\implies x=0$